# How to override method in python object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am using sqlalchemy with postgres/psycopg2 based connection pool in my multi-threaded application. I find that DB connections are getting closed in some code path. I am trying to identify the place in the code where this is happening.

I am using [psycopg2.connect()](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect) to create connections. The [connection object](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection) has a 'close' method that I believe is called to close the connections. In order to find the location, I am trying to override the 'close()' function like this:

```
def newclose(self):
    #print stack
    self.oldclose()

c = psycopg2.connect(...)
c.oldclose = c.close
c.close = types.MethodType(newclose, c)
```

However, I get the error *AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute 'oldclose'*. I tried this technique for classes that I created and it works. I think it may have something to do with the *connection* class being implemented in C as an extension module. Is there any way in which I can patch the connection.close() method ? Is there any other way in which I can find the call stack when connection.close() gets called ? I don't have the option of attaching a debugger. But I can print messages to the console for debugging.

Even the code for replacing the 'close' method is failing (when called separately) - *AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object attribute 'close' is read-only*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than patching the object, you should subclass `Connection` and override `close`:

```
class MyConnection(psycopg2.extensions.connection):
    def close(self):
        # print stack
        super().close()
```

Then you can tell `connect` to use your custom subclass instead.

```
c = psycopg2.connect(connection_factory=MyConnection)
```

Comment: I tried that also. But there is some weird error: *sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) asynchronous connection attempt underway* when sqlalchemy tries to create connections with that change. The error is not there when I use the actual connection object. I didn't try to pursue that further after that. I assumed psycopg2 has some explicit checks that are causing this to fail.

Comment: Sorry. I had tried something slightly different when I got the error. I'll try this and see. Thanks.

Comment: That solved my problem ! Thanks a lot @chepner. I had been struggling with this for a couple of days.